# Publish data with SSDT?

Tags: sql-server-data-tools

I have a SSDT-project. When publishing a new version I want to publish/initialize some data in the database as well. Can that be done using SSDT?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It can be done, but could be tricky. If you set up a variable in the project that can be used for "New" releases, you could put that in your post-deploy script as a section that would run a series of inserts, but only for that "New" type.

As David mentioned, the better way would likely be to use something like Red-Gate's data compare or run the scripts after creating the database. It's possible to do it in post-deploy scripts, but could prove tricky.

Something like this could work:

```
IF '$(DeployType)' = 'New'
BEGIN --"New" release scripts
PRINT 'Post-Deploy Scripts for release.'
:r .\InsertScript1.sql
:r .\InsertScript2.sql
--etc
END --"New" release scripts
```

Comment: It might work to put in some logic into the post-deploy scripts to check for the existence of the records before attempting to run the DML?

Comment: We do that, but this post deploy script just runs the actual scripts. Inside the script, we check for whether or not the data already exists before inserting it. This would just be a way to only run certain scripts if you use a certain value for your project variable.

Also, when we pass in the "New" variable, it is set to run with a "New" Publish profile that always re-creates the database so we don't do much checking in these cases.

Answer (score 2):

This isn't possible in SSDT. The [current guidance](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ssdt/archive/2012/02/02/including-data-in-an-sql-server-database-project.aspx) is to use a post-deployment script.

Redgate [ReadyRoll](http://www.red-gate.com/products/sql-development/readyroll/) provides many experiences familiar to SSDT users, but has improved [static data management](https://documentation.red-gate.com/display/RR1/Static+Data) as well as many other improvements.

Comment: It seems like a post-deployment script means it IS possible though, right?

Comment: Well, in as much as anything is possible in code! What I meant is that there's no special support for static data so you have to run your own code in the post deeply script as a workaround.

Answer (score 1):

We include Merge-scripts automatically, when they are placed in a specific subfolder of the Project.

Comment: We use merge scripts as well and the scripts are auto-generated from another script. These are included explicitly in the post deploy script similar to Peter Schott's answer but without the 'new' check.

Answer (score 0):

depending on what you do, table valued custructors might be something to have a look at:

```
SELECT *
FROM
  (VALUES
    (101, 'Bikes'),
    (102, 'Accessories'),
    (103, 'Clothes')
  ) AS Category(CategoryID, CategoryName);
```

These are easily transported and compared by SSDT.

For ore information see https://www.simple-talk.com/sql/sql-training/table-value-constructors-in-sql-server-2008/